# React app showing blank page in GitHub pages

Tags: reactjs, git, github-pages

After uploading my `react app` on `gitHub pages` its showing a blank page, and there is no error displaying in console. When I inspected the pages it says:

> You need to enable javascript to run this page

but when I checked by browser settings it shows my `javascript` is `enabled`.

**Here is my `console`**

[image]

**Here are the `elements`**

[image]

**Here is the `Package.json`**

[image]

Also when I tested with a basic `react app`(no routes only single page) it was displaying properly

If `gitHub` is not publishing, is there any other alternative to publish my work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks good from my side. You should try with another browser to see if the problem persists.

[image]

Comment: Router was creating problems. I replaced "BrowserRouter" to "HashRouter" in my app and it worked :)

Comment: Had same problem with router, your comment helped, thanks!